# RouterModule : Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined

Tags: angular

I want to get query params from URL. So I used RouterModule to read query params. But I am getting error

> Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined.

I went through similar questions but, in my case, I don't have routes.
All other questions used `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`. What am I doing wrong ?

> Angular 2.4.10
>
> Route 3.4.10

Here is my code.
**module.js**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent, downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { Ng2DeviceDetectorModule } from '/thinkshop/angular2plugins/ng2-device-detector/index.ts';

import { ActivateAccountService } from '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/ActivateAccountService.ts';
import { SupportedDeviceService } '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/service/supporteddeviceservice/supporteddeviceservice.ts'
import { FormContainerComponent } '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/component/formcontainer.component.ts'
import { ActivateAccountComponent } from '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/activateaccount.ts';


const CLIENT_ID = { clientId: "" };
const APP_NAME = 'web-ideolve';
const AUTH_TOKEN = "";
const CAN_EDIT = false;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    Ng2DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot(),
    HttpModule,
    LayoutModule
  ],

  declarations: [
    FormContainerComponent,
    ActivateAccountComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FormContainerComponent,
    ActivateAccountComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Router,
    SupportedDeviceService,
    ActivateAccountService,


    { provide: 'CLIENT_ID', useValue: CLIENT_ID },
    { provide: 'APP_NAME', useValue: APP_NAME },
    { provide: 'AUTH_TOKEN', useValue: AUTH_TOKEN },
    { provide: 'CAN_EDIT', useValue: CAN_EDIT },

  ],
  bootstrap: [FormContainerComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

  showideolvelink = false;

  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    this.showideolvelink = true;
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ActivateAccountService implements OnInit{

    emailId: string= null;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() : void{
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        let encodedParams: any = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.p;

        if(encodedParams != null ){
            var params= JSON.parse(atob(encodedParams));

            this.emailId=  params.email;
        }
    }

    getEmailId() : string{
        return this.emailId;
    }       
}
```

Comment: don't use the `forRoot()`. Should work if you just imports `RouterModule`

Comment: @sheplu Got another error **Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `routes` like following and then add them to `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//Routes
const routes : Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent
}
]


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  // Components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes) // You need to add this 
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Now if you want to get route params you can use : In **AppComponent**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes ,Router,ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
             console.log(params);
      });
}
```

Comment: I don't have `routes`. I want query parameters, that's why i used `router`.

Comment: I used `ActivatedRoute` in my service to read query parameters.

Comment: You can use `ActivatedRoute` to get query params easily. - https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/

Comment: One of the blog given this code to read query params using `ActivateRoute`.

Comment: For `ActivatedRoute` do i need to import `RouterModule` ??

Comment: I don't know. Can you try that. I think it should work. because `ActivatedRoute` is an Interface  https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157365/discussion-between-kaustubh-khare-and-sangwin-gawande).