# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to read URL query parameters, so I am using `RouterModule`. I'm using Angular 2.4.10, with router 3.4.10.

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent, downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import {HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import {LayoutModule} from '@angular/cdk/layout';

import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { Ng2DeviceDetectorModule } from '/thinkshop/angular2plugins/ng2-device-detector/index.ts';

import {httpFactory} from "/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/service/httpRequestInterceptorfactory/httpRequestInterceptorfactory.ts";
import { ActivateAccountService } from '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/ActivateAccountService.ts';
import { SupportedDeviceService } '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/service/supporteddeviceservice/supporteddeviceservice.ts'
import { FormContainerComponent } '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/component/formcontainer.component.ts'
import { ActivateAccountComponent } from '/thinkshop/widgets2/thinkshopapplication/activateaccount/activateaccount.ts';


const CLIENT_ID= {clientId : ""};
const APP_NAME= 'web-ideolve';
const AUTH_TOKEN= "";
const CAN_EDIT= false;

@NgModule({
  imports:  [ 
                BrowserModule,
                UpgradeModule,
                HttpModule,
                RouterModule,
                LayoutModule,
                FlexLayoutModule,
                Ng2DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot()
            ],
    //exports: [RouterModule],      

  declarations: [
                 FormContainerComponent,
                 ActivateAccountComponent
              ],
    entryComponents: [
                      FormContainerComponent,
                      ActivateAccountComponent
                ],
   providers: [
                Router,
                SupportedDeviceService,
                ActivateAccountService,
                 {provide: Http, useFactory: httpFactory, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]},
                 {provide: 'CLIENT_ID', useValue: CLIENT_ID},
                 {provide: 'APP_NAME', useValue: APP_NAME},
                 {provide: 'AUTH_TOKEN', useValue: AUTH_TOKEN},
                 {provide: 'CAN_EDIT', useValue: CAN_EDIT}
       ],
       bootstrap: [ FormContainerComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {

    showideolvelink= false;

    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { 
        this.showideolvelink= true;
    }   
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ActivateAccountService implements OnInit{

    emailId: string= null;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() : void{
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        let encodedParams: any = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.p;

        if(encodedParams != null ){
            var params= JSON.parse(atob(encodedParams));

            this.emailId=  params.email;
        }
    }

    getEmailId() : string{
        return this.emailId;
    }       
}
```

Console error is shown.

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).
```

Note: I am adding encoded parameters from another HTML page to this page and I have a service which will read query param and decode those parameters. That params be like `emailId`, `id`, etc. So I will use that `emailid` for further use.

Comment: Try removing `imports` step by step `Ng2DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot()` then `FlexLayoutModule,` then `LayoutModule` and more likely you will find the cause

Comment: @yurzui If i commented RouterModule then it's working.

Comment: Note `RouterModule` also has static methods `forRoot` and `forChild`: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule

Comment: @yurzui logs prints undefined.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried `forRoot` code, but its giving me another error.  [RouterModule : Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46903887/3148590)

Comment: In the *imports* array?

Comment: Are you sure you have installed @angular/router and its version is the same as other angular dependencies?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that demonstrates this, it's unclear what you have done.

Comment: @yurzui `Angular 2.4.10`

`Route 2.0.0-rc.2`

Comment: It's time to update your dependencies

Comment: @yurzui I can't update Angular. Because i am migrating from 1.x to 2.x.
Route can be possible.

Comment: You're using a release candidate of version 2 of the router? Good grief, why?! Angular 2.0 Final was released with **3.0** of the router, see e.g. http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html. `2.0.0-rc.2` was released in June 2016, and the router part of it was deprecated shortly thereafter. It's no wonder you're having problems.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i upgraded my router version to 3.4.10. Now it's giving dependancy error for `Router` from provider section. **ActivateAccount.html:74 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).(…)**

Comment: @yurzui i upgraded my router version to 3.4.10. Now it's giving dependancy error for `Router` from provider section. **ActivateAccount.html:74 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Router: (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?).(…)**

Comment: Then, again, **[edit] the question** to reflect the actual problem you have. Troubleshooting in the comments is not a valuable use of anyone's time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i will edit my question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register your routes. Check the following code snippet.

app.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

//your routes
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ],
    imports: [
        ...
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes) //register routes
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

add route module under dependencies and restore it.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ....
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    ....
}
```

Comment: I don't have routes. I want query parameters, that's why i have used router

Comment: Did you import router module correctly?
add router module with the version under dependencies in package.json and restore it. You getting undefined because it cannot find under node_module.

Comment: What you gonna do with query param without routes? It would be better if you can explain what you gonna solve.

Comment: I am adding encoded parameters from another html page to this page and I have a service which will read query param and decode those parameters. That params will be **emailId**. So i will use that emailid for further use.

Comment: Seems you have edited your question. Try to set emitDecoratorMetadata option to true under compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json